# DynamoDB: better way to update a table besides querying 1 by 1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to do a weekly update to my table (500 items)

When I receive the updated data, should I take each item, query the corresponding item in DDB, then compare and update if necessary?

or should I try to scan the whole table into memory and compare in memory?

Comment: it depends on the size of your table; if 500 items represents a large-ish portion of the table then scan and update, resolving conflicts as necessary; if the table size is significantly larger than 500 items then just query each item

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is meant for transactional data and performs best in a distributed way when you update one by one. Updating it sequentially will reduce you read cost, while it can take burst reads and writes, you need to have your error handling robust making it to update again upon failure with a delay.

Scanning will also affect the same read and write cost, doing it in a distributed way helps with performance and scalability.

More documentation on distributed writes and performance,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-data-upload.html

Hope it helps.